# Why can't I run the example code of the Python package corpcrawl?

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error

I installed `corpcrawl` but when I try to run this code from [its documentation page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/corpcrawl/0.0.37):

```
 from corpcrawl.crawler import CorpCrawl 

from corpcrawl.backend import Backend

    def main()
```

I get the following error

```
from corpcrawl.crawler import CorpCrawl
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-40-a34fa6bf09cd>", line 1, in <module>
    from corpcrawl.crawler import CorpCrawl

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\corpcrawl\crawler.py", line 1, in <module>
    from parser import Parser

ImportError: cannot import name 'Parser'

def main()
  File "<ipython-input-44-eaaf015e0d6b>", line 1
    def main()
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: The formatting on that page is completely wrong. Not your fault. Are there better instructions inside the source package?

Comment: But I still get the:   from parser import Parser

ImportError: cannot import name 'Parser'

Answer (score 0):

**The code from [corpcrawl's documentation page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/corpcrawl/0.0.37) is broken:**

- Missing `:`
- Wrong indentation
- Illegal characters (such as `“` instead of `"`)

Here is what it should look like (Python 2):

```
from corpcrawl.crawler import CorpCrawl
from corpcrawl.backend import Backend

class MyBackend(Backend):
    def get_company(self, name):
        pass
    def add_company(self, comp):
        print "Adding %s" % str(comp)

def main():
    my_backend = MyBackend()
    crawler = CorpCrawl(cache_path = '/an/absolute/path/to/some/dir', backend = my_backend)
    c.crawl(years = [2011, 2012], quarters = [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I still get:  

from parser import Parser

ImportError: cannot import name 'Parser'

Comment: @Jonathan I can't find this import on the documentation page. Where did you get it?

Comment: by typing " from corpcrawl.crawler import CorpCrawl "


In the tar.gz file there is a parser.py and parser.pyc

Comment: @Jonathan Try this: `from corpcrawl.parser import Parser`

Comment: Really I think you need to talk to the developers.

Comment: @RonanBoiteau , when I run "" from util.words import STATES, COUNTRIES, CORPS, PLACES, BASE_URL, EXHIBIT21_WORDS, JUNK" 


I get the following error

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'